# post request only posting [object Object]

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm new to post/get requests and this is really my first time touching it. I'm having issues where while data is posted from my client side to server side and saved to my database, no matter what it just posts: "[object Object]"

Server side code:

```
 //Recieve new help message
    app.post("/postNewHelp", function(data){
        var newHelp = data;
        console.log(newHelp);
        //Upload to database
        pingdb.all(`UPDATE userHelp SET privateMessage = "${newHelp}"`);
    });
```

Client side:

```
//send new help message
function sendNewHelp() {
    var newHelpMessage = document.getElementById("userHelpSetting").innerHTML;
    console.log (newHelpMessage);
    //Send to serverside
    $.post("/postNewHelp", newHelpMessage), function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
    alert("Done! your changes should now be in effect.");
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `${newHelp}` translates the object to the string("[object Object]")

Comment: can we know what information are you saving on element "userHelpSetting", because now you are sending only an string and cannot be parsed as i guess

Answer (score 0):

Try to name your data like that.

```
$.post("/postNewHelp", {helpText:JSON.stringify(newHelpMessage)}), function(data){
    console.log(data);
}
```

And in your server side you can find your date like that.

```
var helpText = data.helpText
```

But, while you are using jQuery, don't hesitate to use that in your client side.

```
var newHelpMessage = $("#userHelpSetting").text();
```

Please feel free to read about [JSON Stringify](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp) and [JSON parse](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Check the client side code. If possible send the parameter as json object as below

```
function sendNewHelp() {
    var newHelpMessage = document.getElementById("userHelpSetting").innerHTML;
    console.log (newHelpMessage);

    //Send to serverside
    $.post("/postNewHelp", {"help": newHelpMessage}, function(data){
        console.log(data);
        alert("Done! your changes should now be in effect.");
    });

}
```

Now on the server side

```
//use the body parser 
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
   extended: true
}));



app.post("/postNewHelp", function(req, res){
    var newHelp = req.body.help;
    console.log(newHelp);
    //Upload to database
    pingdb.all(`UPDATE userHelp SET privateMessage = "${newHelp}"`);
});
```